# ActiveAdmin Sidebar Ordering in Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When you add a sidebar in the index view, it shows up *after* the filter sidebar.

I'd like my own sidebar to appear before the filter sidebar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following:

```
ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base.class_eval do
        # Renders the sidebar
        def build_sidebar
          a = []
          sidebar_sections_for_action.collect do |section|
            a = [a, section].flatten.compact
          end   
          div id: "sidebar" do
            a.reverse.each do |section|
              sidebar_section(section)
            end
          end
        end
end
```

save the above in app/admin/active_admin_extensions.rb,
good luck.